# Function that accepts type discriminator and the partial type, then returns the complete type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am struggling with TS generics a bit here. I have a bunch of types (here called `Animals`) which all have the attribute "type", unique for each type. I also have a function `createAnimal` which accepts the type of animal as well as a partial of the given animal. It finally returns an Animal based on the type sent in to the function.

The issue I have is that I can not figure out how to type `partial` of `createAnimal`, as well as its return type.

```js
type Dog = {
  type: 'dog';
  name: string;
  barks: true;
};

type Cat = {
  type: 'cat';
  name: string;
  meows: true;
};

type Animals = Dog | Cat;

const createDog = (partial?: Partial<Dog>): Dog => {
  return { type: 'dog', name: 'doggy', barks: true, ...partial };
};

const createCat = (partial?: Partial<Cat>): Cat => {
  return { type: 'cat', name: 'catty', meows: true, ...partial };
};

// These types are wrong. See comment where I use this function to understand what I am looking for.
const createAnimal = <A extends Animals, T extends A['type'], P extends Partial<Animals>>(type: T, partial: P): A => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'dog':
      return createDog(partial);
    case 'cat':
      return createCat(partial);
  }
};
// I would like createAnimal to return the type Cat here and the second argument should be type safe to Cat
const customCat = createAnimal('cat', { name: 'kitty' });
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKPzyw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to define a utility type based on `Animals` that represents a simple mapping from `type` to the associated animal type:

```
type AnimalMap = { [A in Animals as A["type"]]: A }
/* type AnimalMap = {
    dog: Dog;
    cat: Cat;
} */
```

(That uses [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to pick out the keys from `Animals`)  Then your `createAnimal` function should have the following call signature:

declare const createAnimal: (
type: K,
partial: Partial<AnimalMap[K]>
) => AnimalMap[K];

This will let the compiler infer `K` directly from the `type` argument, and use it to narrow `partial` and the return type.  As shown here:

```
const customCat = createAnimal('cat', { name: 'kitty' });
// const customCat: Cat
```

---

As for the implementation of `createAnimalMap`, if you leave it the way you have it the compiler will complain; you can't currently use `switch`/`case` or other [control flow to narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) *type parameters* like `K`.  There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) to support that, but for now it's not part of the language.

You can always just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and the like to silence the complaints, but that's ugly:

```
const createAnimal2 = <K extends keyof AnimalMap>(
  type: K,
  partial: Partial<AnimalMap[K]>
): AnimalMap[K] => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'dog':
      return createDog(partial as Partial<Dog>) as AnimalMap[K];
    //                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    case 'cat':
      return createCat(partial as Partial<Cat>) as AnimalMap[K];
    //                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
  throw new Error();
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

If you want to have the compiler verify what you're doing as safe, you'll need to refactor so that it can understand.  The compiler does better with generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

So we make a `createAnimalMap` of a mapped type over the properties of `AnimalMap`:

```
const createAnimalMap: { [K in keyof AnimalMap]:
  (partial?: Partial<AnimalMap[K]>) => AnimalMap[K]
} = {
  cat: createCat,
  dog: createDog
}
```

And then we can index into it and call the result inside `createAnimal()`:

```
const createAnimal = <K extends keyof AnimalMap>(
  type: K,
  partial: Partial<AnimalMap[K]>
): AnimalMap[K] => {
  return createAnimalMap[type](partial); // okay
};
```

That compiles with no error; since `createAnimalMap`'s type is mapped over `keyof AnimalMap`, then `createAnimmalMap[K]` is seen as being of the single type `(partial?: Partial<AnimalMap[K]>) => AnimalMap[K]`, so it accepts the `partial` parameter as an argument, and returns `AnimalMap[K]`, as claimed by the call signature.  Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAEQPYHM4F44G9RzpWALjgHIATVEgblzgDsBDAWxmIGcwAnASzpRpB4ARg04BrNsS4BXGAIC+A0AXgBhBmAzZaK4iQDGG6rUYt2XXv1oskAd0n5OshUvDR4AQTrcmDADZsWshoAD5w6mCu+kh0HHD6nDAaMMFaABRQomDc-gD8xAAKWTl+ADzBAHwAlMSp6BXagnCJYNKcdNj47noUKCQANPTMrKS9KBADcCLiDjIwgwB0S5mc2f5wiqCbIKDRsZoJSWAwEekra375cEWrJaUR1cSn9Y14LW0dWF1EpIZgk6YRgYNJBJjZ7FInPM4EsFucShsXKBlO44F4fP4ALIMKBaL4AbQ8cF4aO8vgCcAYgQ8+IARCpaQBdRnEInyUAAegAVN9PGSsTi8bQ8L1aqgBHg8H8nhoFHAuRzkSA9nFDsl0eTsVBiASANLEjpiGAQJAAM1JGL8WpZtAyxTyhXtZQ1Aqg+N1jOqGAaLqtOPdjK2Qqa0viiWSEX6tFFYaOKVQW12MVV4eOvq0pX1MAAHsc6GRAkaTebfVqKmkdN04Lqo014f5Hbd-KVS-6PRVQDULZq24zva9mjBWu1Y+r+X63SpGXam34qkidsrkwdUzBfR42GwYLcYhms7mYPnC8azd3XeXKz8a7R635GxcW+OtQGOyAu623R7+zgmmxbNwwH0AALOA0hUKoBylKl4HIShCGFSV3hHNVjmCGcLkpQIbgfSoIKpM8JwDCVJQ5DlJXIijKKogA9Wi6Pohi8AY5j6IQwwt1+Ix4KacikI6FCTg0dCEXw7C7gePDqSfXtiLwUiqIUxS4BYlSmJU5jaHZJowCAzg7HoGBbDgABRTg9M4NJ51oeT1IYrYomXeJpA4JAmGeUc03HNJgX+QYvkBPQxAA0ENiskB5JVA5nLAVyIhlMAlSAA)

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough answer - it really taught me a lot.